# Why does nested React modal automatically trigger function call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, react-responsive-modal

I'm using react-responsive-modal but I've also tried swapping it out for react-modal - same result. I'm also using react-hook-form for all forms.

I've got one modal that triggers another. The first modal that comes up, loads another component - a form. The modal nested in the form is another form. When I pull up the first form, all works great. When I pull up the nested modal, the function for submitting the form in the first modal, is triggered automatically. This makes no sense to me and shouldn't be possible.

Page that loads the first modal, which also contains the function, passed to the first form, which is the one that is being triggered automatically, unexpectedly.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Modal } from "react-responsive-modal";

import ContextButton from "../global/context_button";
import ProfileEdit from "./profile_edit";

const ProfileBodyHeader = props => {
    const [editModalOpen, setEditModalOpen] = useState(false);

    const onEditClick = () => {
        setEditModalOpen(true);
    };

    /** THIS gets triggered automatically when second modal is called up **/
    const onEditSave = async profileData => {
        let updateRes = await updateProfileCombined(profileData);
        if (!updateRes) {
            return;
        }
        setEditModalOpen(false);
    };

    const onEditCancel = () => {
        setEditModalOpen(false);
    };

    const onEditClose = () => {
        setEditModalOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div className="profile-body-header-container">
            <div className="profile-body-header-content">
                <div className="profile-body-header-icons">
                    <div>
                        <ContextButton icon="bytesize:edit" onClick={() => onEditClick()} />
                        <Modal open={editModalOpen} onClose={onEditClose} showCloseIcon={false} center>
                            <ProfileEdit onSave={onEditSave} onCancel={onEditCancel} />
                        </Modal>                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

export default ProfileBodyHeader;

Here's the ProfileEdit component that is loaded into the modal...a form:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import Links from "./links";
import FormError from "../global/form_error";

const ProfileEdit = props => {
    const { onSave, onCancel, isPrimary } = props;

    let defaultValues = getProfileEditDefaults();

    const { register, setValue, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm({ defaultValues });

    return (
        <div className="profile-edit-basic-container">
            <div className="profile-edit-basic-form">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSave)}>
                    <input type="hidden" {...register("is_primary")} />
                    <div>
                        Profile Details
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" {...register("first_name")} />
                        {errors.first_name && <span className="validation">{errors.first_name}</span>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" {...register("last_name")} />
                        {errors.last_name && <span className="validation">{errors.last_name}</span>}
                    </div>
                    
                    ...other fields
                    
                    <div>
                        Social Links
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Links isSocial={true} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="profile-edit-basic-buttons">
                        <button type="submit" className="form-button">Save</button>
                        <button type="button" className="form-button" onClick={() => onCancel()}>Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                    <FormError errors={errors} showDevMessage={true} />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProfileEdit;
```

Here's the nested Links component. You can see there's a LinksList and a LinksEdit, and that I did it the same way as the top-level form. It's the loading of this second modal that's causing the auto submission of the first form.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Modal } from "react-responsive-modal";

import ContextButton from "../global/context_button";
import LinksList from "./links_list";
import LinksEdit from "./links_edit";

const Links = props => {
    let { isSocial } = props;

    const [selectedEntity, setSelectedEntity] = useState(null);
    const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

    const onEditClick = async () => {
        setModalOpen(true);
    };

    const onEditSave = async link => {
        let updateRes = await save(link);
        if (!updateRes) {
            return;
        }
        setSelectedEntity(null);
        setModalOpen(false);
    };

    const onEditCancel = async () => {
        setSelectedEntity(null);
        setModalOpen(false);
    };

    const onEditClose = async () => {
        setModalOpen(false);
    };

    const onEditDelete = async () => {
        let deleteRes = await remove(selectedEntity);
        if (!deleteRes) {
            return;
        }
        setSelectedEntity(null);
        setModalOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div id="links" className="links-container">
            <div className="links-header-container">
                <div className="links-header-body">
                    <div className="links-header-title">
                        Links
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="links-header-edit">
                    {/** WHETHER I click this... **/}
                    <ContextButton icon="carbon:add-alt" onClick={() => onEditClick()} />
                </div>
            </div>
            {/** ...OR I click the edit pencil from the list here, the onEditSave handler in ProfileBodyHeader is automatically triggered **/}
            <LinksList isSocial={isSocial} setSelectedEntity={setSelectedEntity} />
            <Modal open={(modalOpen || selectedEntity)} onClose={onEditClose} showCloseIcon={false} center>
                <LinksEdit isSocial={isSocial} selectedEntity={selectedEntity} onSave={onEditSave} onCancel={onEditCancel} onDelete={onEditDelete} />
            </Modal>                    
        </div>
    );
};

export default Links;
```

This Links component is used outside of the nested modal as well. My grand plans of reusing it w/o a ton of modification, might not happen I guess. I dunno if I have an overlapping event handler name, or something that's causing this. I went through the exercise of renaming all the event handlers in these, to even more specific names, and it didn't work. I can't spot the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround...I guess. It's ugly, but it's the best I could do with what I know.

I couldn't prevent the parent form from submitting when the child modal opens, but I was able to prevent the submit by testing isDirty from from the formState object in the useForm hook, like so:

```
const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors, isDirty } } = useForm({ defaultValues });
```

...

```
const handleEditSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!isDirty) return;
    await handleSubmit(onSave)(e);
};
```

If there's a "right way" to do this, I'd love to know what it is!